# Calculating coordinates using destPoint function in R

Tags: r, matrix, geospatial, google-earth

I have a large dataframe in R consisting of 13449 observations across 62 variables. My end goal is to create polygons in Google Earth for each of the unique Cellnames observations in my dataframe. As far as I'm aware I can only do this by calculating the coordinates for each of the Cellnames variable in R and then pass this to a KML/KMZ for plotting. In order to do this I intend to use the destPoint function in the geosphere package to calculate each of the coordinates in each cell.

The destPoint function uses the following input variables:

```
destPoint(p, b, d)

where p = lat long in degrees
      b = bearing in degrees
      d = distance in meters
```

In my dataframe I have the source lat long across two variables and have the bearings (V1-V7) in a matrix. Where this gets tricky is that the distance needs to be calculated across a range of values for each cell as per below which are stored in a matrix called prach4.

**prach4**

```
From    To
0       234
234     468
468     936
936     1170
1170    1638
1638    2106
2106    3042
3042    3978
3978    4914
4914    6084
6084    7020
7020    7956
7956    10062
10062   14976
14976   19890
19890   25038
25038   29952
29952   34866
34866   40014
40014   50076
50076   60000
```

**Dataframe data:**

```
Cellnames   Longitude  Latitude   V1    V2    V3   V4   V5    V6    V7
CE0001U21A1 -8.6091171 52.6937329 359.4 9.6   19.8  30  40.2  50.4  60.6
CE0001U21B1 -8.6091171 52.6937329 149.4 159.6 169.8 180 190.2 200.4 210.6
CE0001U21C1 -8.6091171 52.6937329 289.4 299.6 309.8 320 330.2 340.4 350.6
CE0001U21A2 -8.6091171 52.6937329 359.4 9.6   19.8  30  40.2  50.4  60.6
CE0001U21B2 -8.6091171 52.6937329 149.4 159.6 169.8 180 190.2 200.4 210.6
CE0001U21C2 -8.6091171 52.6937329 289.4 299.6 309.8 320 330.2 340.4 350.6
```

In order to help visualise the problem I have drawn what I am trying to achieve.

[image: A typical cell layout]

This image below represents a single cell in my dataframe. For each cell there are 0-20 classes where each class represents a distance measurement from the cellname lat and long coordinate, see prach4 above, class 0 is from 0m (cellname lat & long) to 234m, class 1 is from 234m to 468m and so on. For each class in each cell I need to calculate the boundary coordinates using the bearings in V1-V7.

If there are 20 classes with 14 points in each class (8 in class 0) that works out at 274 lat long coordinate pairs per cell. With 13449 cells that works out at 3,685,026 coordinate pairs on top of the existing dataframe which is 5916096 bytes! Should a core i7 with 8GB of RAM be capable of calculating this?? If needs be I can scale back the analysis to a single entity in the network which could dramatically reduce the computation required.

If you could gently steer me in the direction of how to recursively calculate these points for each cell I would be very grateful.

Comment: please provide your data as `dput()`

Comment: Hi loki, would a CSV suffice? I have run the dput on a subset of the original data but I keep getting the original file, I guess that's the whole point of it. There's some commercially sensitive info in the original file that I don't want to publish to the web. In the CSV I have modified some of the details i.e names blah blah. If this works here is a link to a sample of the data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15dQMW8yYj-oVNFbKrjn89gvqr5BjKqqmuB0A1ET4R0M